# How do you show agreement between polygons based on hand-drawn maps?

Tags: qgis, polygon, map-drawing

I'm somewhat new to GIS, coming from a linguistic background, and now I'm trying to make QGIS do something that I want from that background. I have some hand drawn maps with certain areas of the Netherlands circled. I want to see how much agreement these drawings show. I've dutifully entered these maps in a polygon shapefile, but now I'm stuck. 
Now I know (from a brief description in an article) that in ArcGIS this should be relatively easy using Union and Frequency, but I cannot seem to find out how to do this in QGIS. Is it at all possible to make a heat map based on polygons, or do I need to use some other process?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Mart! There is a **Union** tool in QGIS (_Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Union_) which will combine the polygons. Personally, I prefer using **Difference** (from the same list as Union), as the output will only show areas which **are not** in agreement. Also, heatmaps tend to use point layers as input. You could instead use **Interpolation** for polygons :)